# Can't apply for Universal App Quick Start Program - Apple

Tags: ios, macos

When I want to apply for Universal App Quick Start Program, I got the following error message:

> Sorry, you're not eligible to apply.
>
> To apply for the Universal App Quick Start Program,
> your Apple ID must be associated with the Account Holder of an eligible program.
>
> To sign in with a different Apple ID, sign out.

I wonder if anyone knows what this is about?

[image: Apple Universal Quick Start Program error message]

Answer (score 1):

To be eligible to apply, you must be an Account Holder of the **Apple Developer Program** and located in one of the following countries or regions:

- Australia
- Austria
- Belgium
- Canada
- China
- Czech Republic
- Denmark
- Finland
- France
- Germany
- Hong Kong
- Hungary
- Ireland
- Italy
- Japan
- Luxembourg
- Mexico*
- Netherlands
- New Zealand
- Norway
- Poland
- Portugal
- Russia*
- Singapore*
- South Korea*
- Spain
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- Taiwan*
- United Kingdom
- United States

Priority will be given to applicants with an existing macOS application, as availability is limited.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/universal/